# Google OAuth is not working on Streamlit deployed webapp

Tags: python, web-applications, google-oauth, streamlit

I am encountering an error shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iggoI.png). I have included the following code in both my secrets and .toml files:

```ini
[installed]
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID="some client code from Google"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET="some client code from Google"
GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI="https://agilerap.streamlit.app/Candidate_Login"
```

I am just creating a simple login page in streamlit before the user enters the app. It was working perfectly fine on my local system, but I got this error after deploying the app. I am unsure why I am still receiving the error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you haven't allow-listed the URL of your deployed app via the settings for the Google API that you're using. There should be a section where you can add the URL where users will be signing in via Google.

Answer (score 0):

Install:

```
pip install StreamlitGAuth
```

```
import streamlit as st
from google_auth import Google_auth


client_id = "hasjh5jk498ufiu3h89g8-aghdszjhk3k.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client_secret = "afsghfbkhfdjdsgfdjhfjkfhjkfhkjhkjdhks"

login = Google_auth(clientId=client_id, clientSecret=client_secret)

if login == "authenticated":
    # your streamlit applciation
    pass

else:
    st.warning("login failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://pypi.org/project/StreamlitGAuth/2.0.9/)

```
import streamlit as st
from StreamlitGauth.google_auth import Google_auth

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8501"

login = Google_auth(clientId=client_id, 
 clientSecret=client_secret,redirect_uri=redirect_uri
 )

if login == "authenticated":
   st.success("hello")
   pass
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).